# Panel inside asp.net gridview - how can I find it in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I've got a panel inside a gridview.
When I click a radio button in my grid view I call the jquery `click` event
of the radio button.  That part is working fine...now I need to reference the panel that is inside my gridview, but I cannot use `$this` because that refers to my radiobuttonlist (i think it does).

How can I get a reference to this panel.

```
            $("#MainContent_gvLineItems input[id*='rbAnswer']").click(function () {
                var p = $(this).find('[id$=MainContent_gvLineItems_pnlAnswer]'); // find the panel but this wont work so what can I do here?
            });
```

I dont know if my syntax is even right for `id$=MainContent_gvLineItems_pnlAnswer` being that the panel id changes for each row in the grid view...

## Edit

Here is some of the grid view:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Answer">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                               <div id="dMainAnswer">
                                <asp:RadioButtonList ToolTip="Please provide an answer to the method." RepeatDirection="Horizontal" ID="rbAnswer" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.AnswerID")%>'>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="Yes" style="color:green;"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="No" style="color:red;"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="N/A" Value="N/A" style="color:gray;"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="" style="display: none" />
                                </asp:RadioButtonList>
                                   <asp:Panel ID="pnlAnswer" runat="server" Visible="False">
                                       <div id="dMainAnswerResponsibleType">
                                            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbRespType" ToolTip="Select responsible contact type." runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" AutoPostBack="true" SelectedValue='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.ResponsiblePartyType")%>' OnSelectedIndexChanged="rbRespType_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                                <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="TKSE" Value="TKSE">TKSE</asp:ListItem>
                                                <asp:ListItem Text="Other" Value="Other">Other</asp:ListItem>
                                                <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="" style="display: none" />
                                            </asp:RadioButtonList>
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="dMainAnswerResponsible"><a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="info">Res:<span>Select who is responsible in resolving this issue.</span></a>
                                             <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEmployees" runat="server" 
                                                DataSource="<%# GetEmployees() %>" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("TKSEContact") %>' DataTextField="FullName" Width="75px"
                                                DataValueField="FullName" 
                                                ToolTip="Select the TKSE responsible party.">
                                            </asp:DropDownList>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtContact" Text='<%# Eval("ResponsiblePartyContact") %>' Width="75px" MaxLength="50" runat="server" ToolTip="Enter the responsible contact name." Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="dDueDate"><a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="info">Due:<span>Select the due date when you expect this issue to be resolved.</span></a>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDueDate" Text='<%# Eval("DueDate") %>' Width="59px" runat="server" ToolTip="Select the due date." CssClass="datePickerDueDate"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="cSendToSugar">
                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSendToSugar" ToolTip="Send/Update issue to Sugar?" BackColor="Gold" Text="Send To Sugar?" Checked="true" runat="server" />
                                        </div>
                                   </asp:Panel>
                               </div>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                                <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Notice the panel `pnlAnswer`, its initially set to invisible `Visible=False`.  It also isnt a sibling of the radiobutton list..at least I dont think it is...

Comment: If you have many panels, and many radio buttons, in this case is easy to locate the first panel that is near the radio button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use .parents to find the parents of the element; if you give it a css class, you can do:

```
$(this).parents(".class:first")
```

To find it.  I assume the panel is a parent to the radiobuttonlist.  Otherwise, you'd want to use another Jquery method.  This works as long as the panel is visible, or hidden using:

```
<asp:Panel .. style="display:none" />
```

Comment: But initially this panel is not visible (runat=server visible=false in my asp.net) so I dont think I can use client id can I?

Comment: Visible="false" does not render to the client, so you will never find the panel.  If you want the panel to be accessible, set style="display:none;" on the panel instead.

Comment: the issue is the radiobuttonlist is NOT inside the panel it is outside of it..so how does parents help me ?

Comment: @oJM86o what do you mean by outside? Can you post your markup.  it's so hard to tell you the right method to use without it.

Comment: Hi Brian thank you for being patient, I posted my markup can you look at it please.

Comment: No problem.  It is the sibling of the first radio button list, possibly.  Remember that server controls may render an unpredictable amount of HTML, which could be throwing this off.  Since you are attaching to the input, you may need to drill up to the parent, and then use find to find the panel.  Assuming you give the panel a css class of "Answer", you could do: .parents("div[id='dMainAnswer']").find(".Answer:first")

Comment: @oJM86o also, this will NEVER work when Visible="false".  That's because it never renders to the client.

Comment: Basically I have a `RadioButtonList` called `rbAnswer` when they select the value No (there are 3 values Yes, No, or N/A).  If they select No I want to make the Panel `pnlAnswer` visible so that further controls can be shown.  By default it is set to invisible because there are a lot of controls inside of it.

Comment: can you edit your answer with how I need to do this, Im still a bit confused or can we move it to chat?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15730/discussion-between-brian-mains-and-ojm86o)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest giving your panel a css class and then using jQuery selectors. If the radio button is a [sibling](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) of the panel:

```
var panel = $(this).siblings(".answer");
```

It depends where the panel sits in the generated markup, perhaps next or prev can be used instead. If you post the generated markup, I can update this answer.

---

Now we can see the markup (thanks) you need the parent and then the sibling like so:

```
 <someOtherElement> <!-- the grid view container -->
    <div class="answer"></div> <!-- sibling of parent (maybe <div runat="server"> is better than panel?)  -->
    <div> <!-- parent -->
        <input type="radio">  <!-- this -->
    </div>
 </someOtherElement>
```

Comment: The issue is the radio button list is outside of the panel not inside of it so it is not a sibling.

Comment: @oJM86o by outside do you mean the radio button list is in the panel as a parent/child relationship?

Comment: @BrianMains - see my markup, the radiobuttonlist comes before the panel.  They are seperate not parent / child.  Basically when you click the radio button (the value No) then the panel should open.  Right now I have code that gets the value No, so now I need to get a reference of the panel and show it (because they selected no).